# how can i send random user agent in scrapy with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo, faker

In scrapy, I want to send a different useragent for each request. So I put headers:'random user agent' in each request. Scrapy works fine without pymongo. But when I run it with pymongo, it keeps freezing. I do not know the reason. It would be nice if you let me know.

For reference, when the scrapy-fake-useragent middleware is used, it works well without pymongo, but when it is used with pymongo, it continues to freeze, so it is not used.

this code works fine(without pymongo)

```
import scrapy


from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

class TesterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tester4'
  
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.amazon.jp', callback=self.router_start, dont_filter=True)

    def router_start(self, response):
        link = ['https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=s9_acss_bw_cts_Computer_T1_w?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A16225007011%2Cn%3A172456&bbn=16225007011&ie=UTF8&qid=1487012920&rnid=16225007011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_r=PF0Q3FXYDG3N1QMXFA8Y&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=74069509-93ef-4a3c-8dca-a9e3fa773a64&pf_rd_i=16225007011','https://www.amazon.com/s?bbn=16225007011&rh=n%3A16225007011%2Cn%3A193870011&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&pf_rd_i=16225007011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=74069509-93ef-4a3c-8dca-a9e3fa773a64&pf_rd_r=PF0Q3FXYDG3N1QMXFA8Y&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1487012920&rnid=16225007011&ref=s9_acss_bw_cts_Computer_T2_w','https://www.amazon.com/s?bbn=16225007011&rh=n%3A16225007011%2Cn%3A13896617011&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&pf_rd_i=16225007011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=74069509-93ef-4a3c-8dca-a9e3fa773a64&pf_rd_r=PF0Q3FXYDG3N1QMXFA8Y&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1487012920&rnid=16225007011&ref=s9_acss_bw_cts_Computer_T3_w','https://www.amazon.com/s?bbn=16225007011&rh=n%3A16225007011%2Cn%3A172504&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&pf_rd_i=16225007011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=74069509-93ef-4a3c-8dca-a9e3fa773a64&pf_rd_r=PF0Q3FXYDG3N1QMXFA8Y&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1487012920&rnid=16225007011&ref=s9_acss_bw_cts_Computer_T4_w']
     
  
        for i in link:  
            Faker.seed(fake.random_number())

            yield scrapy.Request(url=i, callback=self.product_1,  priority=200000, dont_filter=True, meta={'link':i},headers={'User-Agent': fake.chrome()})
 
    def product_1(self, response):
        Faker.seed(fake.random_number())
        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.meta['link'] + ' ', callback=self.product, dont_filter=True,headers={'User-Agent': fake.chrome()})


    def product(self, response):

        for i in range(1,10):
            print(i)
```

but, this code doesn't work well (with pymongo)

```
import scrapy
import pymongo

connection = pymongo.MongoClient()
db_link = connection.CoupangLinkTestDB  
db_product = connection.CoupangLinkProductTestDB


from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

class TesterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tester4'
  
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.amazon.jp', callback=self.router_start, dont_filter=True)

    def router_start(self, response):
         
        db_start = 50
        db_end = 60

        for i in db_link.product_6.find({})[db_start:db_end]:  
            Faker.seed(fake.random_number())

            yield scrapy.Request(url=i['link'], callback=self.product_1,  priority=200000, dont_filter=True, meta={'link':i['link']},headers={'User-Agent': fake.chrome()})
 
    def product_1(self, response):
        Faker.seed(fake.random_number())
        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.meta['link'] + ' ', callback=self.product, dont_filter=True,headers={'User-Agent': fake.chrome()})


    def product(self, response):

        for i in range(1,10):
            print(i)
```

i add it afert i wrote this question.

1.If scrapy-fake-useragent(or faker) does't work with pymongo, scrapy can collect data and save it into mongodb.

2.If scrapy-fake-useragent(or faker) works with pymongo, scrapy can not collect data.

3.If scrapy-fake-useragent(or faker) works,  without pymongo . scrpay can collect data. because i can check on terminal.

Comment: To follow up on our previous conversation (assuming this is your second account), have you confirmed that this works when you aren't using random user agents? I'd be surprised if that is what is causing your issue...

Comment: Also, you say you are now using `scrapy-fake-useragent`, but then you have manual `Faker` calls, so you are either doubling work or not quite understanding how this should be done.

Comment: @Tomjn you are right it is my second account!, in this case, 

1.If scrapy-fake-useragent(or faker) does't work with pymongo, scrapy can collect data and save it into mongodb.

2.If scrapy-fake-useragent(or faker) works with pymongo, scrapy can not collect data. 

3.If scrapy-fake-useragent(or faker) works,  without pymongo . scrpay can collect data. because i can check on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your database is reachable and your database connection settings i.e. mongo URI is correct. Usually when the database is unreachable your code will freeze while it is retrying to reach the database until some sort of timeout an error will be thrown.

One way you can verify your URI is trying to access the database using mongo shell first with the same URI:

```
mongo "mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:28015"
```

How to use mongo shell:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/

Comment: thx to comment ! without ```faker``` and ```scrapy-fake-useragent```, this code can reach to DB becasue i can check collected data